# Hijacking Search History?

Tags: privacy, user-tracking

I accidentally inputted possibly sensitive information into Google search. (my copypaste screwed up and I searched a copy of previously copied information...)

I already cleared search history, but from [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96751/how-is-skype-showing-ads-from-my-google-search-history) I am concerned if either Google or third party can get hold of this information that i inputted.

Is this possible, either by Google or third party?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25202/what-should-i-do-if-i-type-my-password-in-the-address-bar-or-type-password-in-g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll never know.

I once happened to input a password. I immediately changed it once I realised this. If your information was a password, you better change it now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is **yes**. Not only "can" they, but certain services *do* collect data (I'll update this answer with references when I get a minute).

Further to this, from using Google Analytics I've seen reports on 'from' where a user came to find my site. So, what they searched in Google will be the referring URL to my site. By this logic, if you typed a password, for example, into google, then visited a site with some analytics running from this search, that site could have access to the value you put into the search box too. Bit of an edge case but, still.

As an aside, the title for this is pretty misleading. Nobody would be hijacking your history in the scenario you've described - they'd be capturing data, sure, but nobody would be manipulating or interrogating your search history as such.